# Trouble Installing SSH with Cygwin

Tags: ssh, cygwin, openssh

I'm using Cygwin (or more specifically zsh installed via Cygwin) and I've installed all of the *ssh* packages including Net/openssh, but when I try to run ssh (or things like ssh-host-config) I get:

```
➜  ~  ssh
zsh: command not found: ssh
➜  ~  ssh-host-config
zsh: command not found: ssh-host-config
```

I would prefer to get ssh working in Cygwin instead of installing Mysisgit if possible.  Any clue what's up?  Thanks in advance for the help!